# How to find out why my PHP API request doesn't work on iOS devices?

Tags: php, ios, curl

So my problem here is following:

I have form on my website, which is basically contact form and I am storing data from that contact form into my excel spreadsheets (using API Spreadsheets -> https://www.apispreadsheets.com/).

When I am using Android device and my PC (Windows) to access the site and fill out the form, everything wents smoothly, I get data filled out on Excel spreadsheets, but when I use iOS devices, it seems that request on API doesn't even go through for some reason.

I know that everything else goes through correctly and smoothly because, after someone confirm form, I have this "thankyou.html" page and I also get an email with data onto my mail, but that data isn't stored onto Excel (which should be, and as I stated before I am using apispreadsheets to do that). And when it comes to sending data onto my email I am using phpmailer.
I checked my error log file, there's nothing wrong in it.

Now as I've no idea what's the problem, I am asking how could I possibly identify the problem?

Form is inside the index.php file, I am using `action="sendmail.php"` and using POST method.
This is code that I am using inside of sendmail.php to create API request:

```
       //FORM SUBMITTING TO SPREADSHEETS
$url= "https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/*/";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$postJSON = json_encode(["data"=> ["name"=>$name,"email"=>$email,"zelim"=>$iwant,"mobile"=>$mobile,"dateandtime"=>$dateandtime,"distributer_name"=>$distemail]]);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postJSON);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($http_code == 201){
    // SUCCESS

}
else{
    // ERROR CODE

}
```

Comment: Is there anyone to know answer on this question?

Comment: How are you actually accessing the POSTed data? Have you logged / made a debug output of all received parameters yet, and compared that between the iOS submission, and a working one?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately I don't have iOS device, so it's not that I can really test it.